How to make a nutella chocolate sauce that stays liquid at room temperature?
I am planning to startup a waffle store, for that I have bought a 750g jar of nutella. I also need to melt a chocolate bar. Now I am willing to make the nutella and chocolate bar less dense or liquify it to be able to pour it as a topping on waffle. The topping needs to stay liquid at room temperature.
I have watched a couple of videos where it is instructed to add a little bit  of water,milk or vegetable oil. What would be the best option to get my desired consistency and most important the flavour need to be the same, and can be left at room temperature?

If your ingredients are solid at room temperature, they'll probably remain solid after being melted and mixed.  As for how to melt a chocolate bar, see What is the best way to melt chocolate?. Note that in a commercial context, a microwave is probably inconvenient, since the chocolate will harden between customers.

I make a Nutella sauce regularly for waffles, the most effective way to thin it out is adding milk. You can use water and it does work as well, although it loses a bit of richness. I would not use oil as it makes the result greasy and unpleasant.
As for pouring chocolate at room temperature the only way I know of is to add oil when it's melted. I don't love the result as it makes it a bit greasy but it does work.
